# Grab keyboard events outside the appliaction in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, events, keyboard

I would need to emit a beep from an MP3 or Wav file each time a key from my keyboard is pressed.

Any idea how to achieve this in Qt ?

In case you are interested on the reason why I need this:

I am using a glass keyboard from Tactys:
 http://www.tactys.com/?page_id=303 
because of pain in the wrist. Unfortunately the default beep of the keyboard is too loud and disturbs my colleagues. Setting the beep off make me press to heavily generating pain in the fingers. 
As I wrote a Time tracker application I would like to enhance it emitting a sound at each key stroke.

Thanks

Comment: Only for a specific OS? I guess Qt doesn't provide it out of the box. You could try [`QxtGlobalShortcut`](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/tip/qxtglobalshortcut.html) from the Qt extension library "Qxt", but possibly that will not work (at least not for modifier keys, as they are not keystrokes identified by applications). For a Linux-only solution: I could think of some xinput hook... Windows: no idea, sorry.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, unfortunately I would need a portable solution as the following one for java: https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/ sorry I just read next answer and it looks like it is portable ...

Comment: Well the Java library sounds more promising than Qxt. If I remember correctly, Qxt can't grab single key presses (especially modifier keys Ctrl, Shift, etc) but only combinations.

Comment: Thanks, indeed I made a simple application in java with the specified lib which solved my problem. It is not integrated in my Qt application but I made it as a service which is fine too for my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @leemes [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936784/grab-keyboard-events-outside-the-appliaction-in-qt/24941708#comment38751455_24936784), you could use [QxtGlobalShortcut](https://github.com/hluk/qxtglobalshortcut). It supports [Linux/X11](https://github.com/hluk/qxtglobalshortcut/blob/master/src/qxtglobalshortcut_x11.cpp), [Mac OS X](https://github.com/hluk/qxtglobalshortcut/blob/master/src/qxtglobalshortcut_mac.cpp) and [Windows](https://github.com/hluk/qxtglobalshortcut/blob/master/src/qxtglobalshortcut_win.cpp) as well as Qt4/5.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows try use this example [C++ Qt 104 - Native Code, Basic Windows KeyLogger](http://youtu.be/O0C4V6JmlNw). In any case it is necessary to use native code. Good luck!

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, unfortunately it should be portable over windows